# google画像検索ではどのように画像を送信しているのですか

Tags: html, html5, http

google画像検索で画像をアップロードすると同じ画像や類似画像を検索することができますが、どのようのGoogleのサーバーにアップロードされているのでしょうか。　
get送信はURLに情報を加えるため大きなサイズのファイルは送信できないと思っていました。
そこでgoogle画像検索のページのソースコードを見たのですが、POST送信の記述は確認できませんでした。
HTMLにお詳しい方、回答を頂けたら大変ありがたいです。
以下　例としてTORのアイコンを画像検索した時のクエリです。

[https://www.google.co.jp/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZitnxgTzuNq（中略）&hl=ja](https://www.google.co.jp/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZitnxgTzuNqQpbY7yo9BMbK5uM7JN3C55-7tt9tTYQ09QkkRm2yZH1m2aWaHMr7rN1tRRHmKck8yfmKpCL5MvOW52MXCP44BuqlfbelL4oPXqesqkQoA5oK15NNcotsP2bSZiUF0B9xakmcBrafKXPep6tccT51iRRftUGWQhuBkp1YlDtzKYacIuhhHv-G5YBfa9vAUp5LW_1chA53hM11y6pCetpcg_11PWS-r9T8x1MN2iiWuled_1ybeZ4WoKcuh-SCoQI-gfb8e2Sac8ZZpkkUT7khTL6qubhTGp5CFHR7GkmC4NviVoV3fb0VCf9M54TzaQ_12T22z8ZTF3Qtg8DAYRm7q4dKe6GTEEgbk-ynuF3daE_1BsFisTuvnEGcIFePsnrDFiwomvUtoETIT7yFLHDc6Duk6WP36jzEOW8dOPE_10_1U4iZysUw_1zKWSBZPuHrHsxrHFbYRiJ-c8AmAHci3x4--pmyv91UR2RRui6nBWHVzNJetJqAPSW2Y1YxegQ1MJdwt-lF5HpH5UqgzRO2qMpZQXnLUQTZzC4OiK4_1NFxikMGDaNLUHLQSiPnDFm3_1dnDBcPualAgguksp-_1GeJikJduV2MeUQp4bEZRRWhiq-viK-CbCm_1vc1bbf3q2nYl7bmY7OtOATxuiBo5ygKogMjhfW50dgdq4vo_1ycv7Oz2hRN3HjjhUcF7_18aNI7X4aMjMZbN1vshXXLm-jRquM7A3Chh1e5Q3qNZfkB_1BXdHQ9YhXtJ2mqRqBqtIMYPju3AebNqQ9DpR0c2sbZdb4TFz7mnGeo4sr-KtEeG0-KQIbymSOSGBaF5pd6yjqmz071KMvnRC43beFoQjhACYY8jonQ8VfFnI1tGYj1CesYnFLqLoo_1MTAQkcV2ZWLL383NFv0K7c-Fd5EmYNifFN1Pl7PJxQLzEHLmul6_1HwrgaV4DKhM_1RjdFuc7mRG759mukQCbGIOTyslCTIVN1J7OxpyEb_1ee5HIdACvo7JgNpItX1eXQpVF9nhRF_1d2XfWGhLD7FzDOXEmL5SFse-c3SpQGDUN0YghA-bDESwsotxGIkAXHq2SxFV6fxbVbfXWjirTCpJi8ubEwsshuzcuexISWPZIepCwbREI8lLsiKFrGzr_1kS5N1uohI5AbM9t0vioXNZwDY9OQaDJm2OSxItuGh2YAUxWS40Ss89bmZLkG5fcJghXRGj82n1u7H7fK_1gRu_1Gp&hl=ja)
<sub>（編注：長いのでリンク文字列を省略しましたが、リンク先は元のままです）</sub>

Answer (score 2):

https://www.google.co.jp/search?tbs=sbi:～

へページ遷移する前に

https://www.google.co.jp/searchbyimage/upload

へPOSTしていますよ。

---

> どのようのGoogleのサーバーにアップロードされているのでしょうか。

GoogleはWebブラウザー毎に動作を切り替えているので一概には答えられないですがたぶん[Ajax](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax)を使用していると思います。

> get送信はURLに情報を加えるため大きなサイズのファイルは送信できないと思っていました。

できる・できないはWebサーバーが決定します（正確には中継するProxyサーバーも影響し得るのですがHTTPSでは影響しません）。仮にGETで送信するという決定がなされたのであればWebサーバーも設定変更し受け入れるまでの話です。

Comment: ご回答、ありがとうございます。大変助かります。現在iOSアプリを作っているのですが、私はHTMLの知識が全然ないので見逃していたのだと思います。大変厚かましいのは承知の上なのですが、私がしているもう一つの質問にもご回答をいただけませんか？
重ねてお礼を言わせていただきます。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @ぬわん さん、加筆しましたがいまいち何を求められているのかわかりませんでした。もう少し知りたい内容を論点を絞って質問されると答えやすいです。

Comment: @sayuyi 様　わかりにくい追加コメントで申し訳ありませんでした。
もう一つの質問というのは<http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/21542/画像検索アプリ-google画像検索にカメラロール内の画像を渡したい-swift>です。

Comment: @ぬわん 分らないから回答していないわけで、催促されたからといって回答できるわけではありません。